# Can't bind to 'graph' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'

Tags: angular, canvas, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test my component that use a directive.
This directive has been created by me to draw a graph. 
But the problem is when i try to test using karma and jasmine i get un error. I couldnt found out. 
When i call my component i got the same error.

This is my html page

```
   <div class="courbe">
    <canvas [graph]="courbe">  
    </canvas>    
   </div>
```

And thats the error:

```
     Error: Template parse errors:
    Can't bind to 'graph' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. ("<div 
     class="courbe">
        <canvas [ERROR ->][graph]="courbe">
        </canvas>
      </div>
```

Can anyone help me please?
Thanks

Comment: Can you share your canvas component code

Comment: It worked. i just have to add the directive "graph" iy the declaration of the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just have to add the directive "graph" in the declaration of the test.